# Forming the best possible poker hand

Tags: python, performance, playing-cards

This is what the function is doing: it gets two arrays of tuples with 5 items each - hand = [H1,H2,H3,H4,H5] and board = [B1,B2,B3,B4,B5]

What I need to do is check all arrays formed by 2 items from hand and 3 items from board, like combination = [Hn,Hm,Bi,Bj,Bk] (100 combinations in total)

Then I need to compare each one of the combinations against a dictionary to get the combination rank, and then return the best array (best rank) and the rank itself:

```
def check_hand(hand, board, dictionary_A, dictionary_B):

 best_hand = []
 first_int = True

 for h1 in range (0, 4):
  for h2 in range (h1+1, 5):
   for b1 in range (0, 3):
    for b2 in range (b1+1, 4):
     for b3 in range (b2+1, 5):
      hand_check = []
      hand_check.append(hand[m1])
      hand_check.append(hand[m2])
      hand_check.append(board[b1])
      hand_check.append(board[b2])
      hand_check.append(board[b3])
      hand_check = sort(hand_check) #Custom sort for my array of objects
      hand_ranks = "".join([str(hand_check[0].rank),str(hand_check[1].rank),str(hand_check[2].rank),str(hand_check[3].rank),str(hand_check[4].rank)])

      if (hand_check[0].suit == hand_check[1].suit and hand_check[1].suit == hand_check[2].suit and hand_check[2].suit == hand_check[3].suit and hand_check[3].suit == hand_check[4].suit):
       control = [dictionary_A[hand_ranks][0],dictionary_A[hand_ranks][1]]
      else:
       control = [dictionary_B[hand_ranks][0],dictionary_B[hand_ranks][1]]

      if first_int:
       best_hand = hand_check
       rank = control
       first_int = False
      elif (int(control[0]) > int(rank[0])):
       rank = control
       best_hand = hand_check       
      elif (int(control[0]) == int(rank[0])):
       if (int(control[1]) > int(rank[1])):       
        rank = control
        best_hand = hand_check      

 return best_hand, rank[0]
```

I need to run this check for 2 million different hands and interact over 1000 times for every hand (Ideally I would run it for at least 100000 times for every hand, for a more statistically accurate result).
Any ideas on how to make it more efficient?

Examples:
I added some "prints" on the way for better understanding:

Hand: Q♥K♥Q♠K♠3♦︎
Board: 2♣2♥J♦︎6♥4♦︎

2♣2♥J♦︎Q♥K♥ - 2♣2♥6♥Q♥K♥ - 2♣2♥4♦︎Q♥K♥ - 2♣6♥J♦︎Q♥K♥ - 2♣4♦︎J♦︎Q♥K♥ -
   2♣4♦︎6♥Q♥K♥ - 2♥6♥J♦︎Q♥K♥ - 2♥4♦︎J♦︎Q♥K♥ - 2♥4♦︎6♥Q♥K♥ - 4♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♥K♥ -
   2♣2♥J♦︎Q♥Q♠ - 2♣2♥6♥Q♥Q♠ - 2♣2♥4♦︎Q♥Q♠ - 2♣6♥J♦︎Q♥Q♠ - 2♣4♦︎J♦︎Q♥Q♠ -
   2♣4♦︎6♥Q♥Q♠ - 2♥6♥J♦︎Q♥Q♠ - 2♥4♦︎J♦︎Q♥Q♠ - 2♥4♦︎6♥Q♥Q♠ - 4♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♥Q♠ -
   2♣2♥J♦︎Q♥K♠ - 2♣2♥6♥Q♥K♠ - 2♣2♥4♦︎Q♥K♠ - 2♣6♥J♦︎Q♥K♠ - 2♣4♦︎J♦︎Q♥K♠ -
   2♣4♦︎6♥Q♥K♠ - 2♥6♥J♦︎Q♥K♠ - 2♥4♦︎J♦︎Q♥K♠ - 2♥4♦︎6♥Q♥K♠ - 4♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♥K♠ -
   2♣2♥3♦︎J♦︎Q♥ - 2♣2♥3♦︎6♥Q♥ - 2♣2♥3♦︎4♦︎Q♥ - 2♣3♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♥ - 2♣3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎Q♥ -
   2♣3♦︎4♦︎6♥Q♥ - 2♥3♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♥ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎Q♥ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎6♥Q♥ - 3♦︎4♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♥ -
   2♣2♥J♦︎Q♠K♥ - 2♣2♥6♥Q♠K♥ - 2♣2♥4♦︎Q♠K♥ - 2♣6♥J♦︎Q♠K♥ - 2♣4♦︎J♦︎Q♠K♥ -
   2♣4♦︎6♥Q♠K♥ - 2♥6♥J♦︎Q♠K♥ - 2♥4♦︎J♦︎Q♠K♥ - 2♥4♦︎6♥Q♠K♥ - 4♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♠K♥ -
   2♣2♥J♦︎K♥K♠ - 2♣2♥6♥K♥K♠ - 2♣2♥4♦︎K♥K♠ - 2♣6♥J♦︎K♥K♠ - 2♣4♦︎J♦︎K♥K♠ -
   2♣4♦︎6♥K♥K♠ - 2♥6♥J♦︎K♥K♠ - 2♥4♦︎J♦︎K♥K♠ - 2♥4♦︎6♥K♥K♠ - 4♦︎6♥J♦︎K♥K♠ -
   2♣2♥3♦︎J♦︎K♥ - 2♣2♥3♦︎6♥K♥ - 2♣2♥3♦︎4♦︎K♥ - 2♣3♦︎6♥J♦︎K♥ - 2♣3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎K♥ -
   2♣3♦︎4♦︎6♥K♥ - 2♥3♦︎6♥J♦︎K♥ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎K♥ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎6♥K♥ - 3♦︎4♦︎6♥J♦︎K♥ -
   2♣2♥J♦︎Q♠K♠ - 2♣2♥6♥Q♠K♠ - 2♣2♥4♦︎Q♠K♠ - 2♣6♥J♦︎Q♠K♠ - 2♣4♦︎J♦︎Q♠K♠ -
   2♣4♦︎6♥Q♠K♠ - 2♥6♥J♦︎Q♠K♠ - 2♥4♦︎J♦︎Q♠K♠ - 2♥4♦︎6♥Q♠K♠ - 4♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♠K♠ -
   2♣2♥3♦︎J♦︎Q♠ - 2♣2♥3♦︎6♥Q♠ - 2♣2♥3♦︎4♦︎Q♠ - 2♣3♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♠ - 2♣3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎Q♠ -
   2♣3♦︎4♦︎6♥Q♠ - 2♥3♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♠ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎Q♠ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎6♥Q♠ - 3♦︎4♦︎6♥J♦︎Q♠ -
   2♣2♥3♦︎J♦︎K♠ - 2♣2♥3♦︎6♥K♠ - 2♣2♥3♦︎4♦︎K♠ - 2♣3♦︎6♥J♦︎K♠ - 2♣3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎K♠ -
   2♣3♦︎4♦︎6♥K♠ - 2♥3♦︎6♥J♦︎K♠ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎J♦︎K♠ - 2♥3♦︎4♦︎6♥K♠ - 3♦︎4♦︎6♥J♦︎K♠ -

Best Hand: 2♣2♥J♦︎K♥K♠ Rank: 3

Just wondering if there is a way to run the piece of code below more efficiently. I just started to get acquainted with parallel program and think this might be an answer? But I have no idea how to do it using imap or processes.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Is this real working Python code? (Introducing a comment with `//` is not syntactically valid.) What's `mao`? Also, please provide some example inputs and outputs so that we can better understand what this code accomplishes.

Comment: The comment is not in the original code. It is a working code. What I am trying to accomplish is to find a better way to interact 100 times between hand and board. I updated the original post with examples.

Comment: In your example, 2s5h3sTc looks like an incomplete combination. Also, you still haven't explained what `mao[m1]` is.

Comment: Yes, it was incomplete. And mao = hand (also updated that).

Comment: Python being a dynamically typed language, it is not obvious what representation your code expects for cards. A detailed runnable example would be better than a prettified one.

Comment: I generalized my problem to make it easier o understand. I need this to be more efficient to be able to run it a lot (billions) of times.

Comment: This site is for reviewing actual code. I've rolled it back to the code as it was when I reviewed it, not the hypothetical replacement.

Comment: @Graipher, that's not directly relevant: the edit was made while I was writing my answer and before I posted it. But I consider the rollback justified because the edit wasn't improving the code but replacing it wholesale with code which didn't do anything remotely similar.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fair enough. If I had had to consider rolling back the edit I would have checked the timestamps and noticed it, but since I only saw your comment, I didn't bother...my bad.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
>  for h1 in range (0, 4):
>   for h2 in range (h1+1, 5):
>    for b1 in range (0, 3):
>     for b2 in range (b1+1, 4):
>      for b3 in range (b2+1, 5):
>       hand_check = []
>       hand_check.append(hand[m1])
>       hand_check.append(hand[m2])
>       hand_check.append(board[b1])
>       hand_check.append(board[b2])
>       hand_check.append(board[b3])
> ```

Use `itertools` for this kind of thing:

```
for h in itertools.combinations(hand, 2):
  for b in itertools.combinations(board, 3):
    hand_check = list(h) + list(b)
```

Also, I don't find `hand_check` to be a helpful name. In general I expect variable names to be nouns (unless they're Booleans, when predicates make sense), and when I parse `hand_check` as a noun I find that it's a `check` modified by `hand`. The smallest change would be to rename it `hand_to_check`; I prefer `candidate_hand`.

---

> ```
>       if (hand_check[0].suit == hand_check[1].suit and hand_check[1].suit == hand_check[2].suit and hand_check[2].suit == hand_check[3].suit and hand_check[3].suit == hand_check[4].suit):
> ```

Ugh. Use `set`.

```
if len(set(card.suit for card in hand_check)) == 1:
```

---

> ```
>       hand_check = sort(hand_check) #Custom sort for my array of objects
>       hand_ranks = "".join([str(hand_check[0].rank),str(hand_check[1].rank),str(hand_check[2].rank),str(hand_check[3].rank),str(hand_check[4].rank)])
> ```

> ```
>        control = [dictionary_A[hand_ranks][0],dictionary_A[hand_ranks][1]]
>       else:
>        control = [dictionary_B[hand_ranks][0],dictionary_B[hand_ranks][1]]
> ```

Firstly, why the quadruple-lookup? Why not

```
lookup_table = dictionary_A if only_one_suit else dictionaryB
control = lookup_table[hand_ranks]
```

?

Secondly, although Python's string manipulation is quite fast, since you're aiming to microoptimise you should think in terms of integers rather than strings. I'd delve into the fascinating world of [perfect hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) to try to get a lookup table which fits into L2 cache, or maybe even L1 with luck (there are only 6188 multisets of 5 ranks, so less than 25 kB of lookup table suffices).

---

> ```
>       if first_int:
>        best_hand = hand_check
>        rank = control
>        first_int = False
>       elif (int(control[0]) > int(rank[0])):
>        rank = control
>        best_hand = hand_check       
>       elif (int(control[0]) == int(rank[0])):
>        if (int(control[1]) > int(rank[1])):       
>         rank = control
>         best_hand = hand_check
> ```

If you initialise `rank` to `[-1]` then you should be able to eliminate `first_int` and simplify this to

```
      if (control > rank):
        rank = control
        best_hand = hand_check
```

---

Now, I've addressed micro-optimisation above, but the first rule of optimisation is to start by looking at the algorithm.

> What I need to do is check all arrays formed by 2 items from hand and
>   3 items from board, like combination = [Hn,Hm,Bi,Bj,Bk] (100
>   combinations in total)
>
> Then I need to compare each one of the combinations against a
>   dictionary

is wrong. What you **need** to do is find the set of five cards formed by 2 cards from the hand and 3 cards from the board which has the highest score.

I'd suggest that you micro-optimise and then benchmark against a major restructuring with the following outline:

```
for suit in the_four_suits:
  hand_mask = build_mask((card for card in hand if card.suit == suit))
  board_mask = build_mask((card for card in board is card.suit == suit))
  check_royal_flush(hand_mask, board_mask)
  check_straight_flush(hand_mask, board_mask)
  check_flush(hand_mask)

hand_counts = count_by_ranks(hand)
board_counts = count_by_ranks(board)
check_four_of_a_kind(hand_counts)
check_full_house(hand_counts)
...
```

The key ideas are to do everything with bit manipulation and to return as soon as you know that no further checks will produce a hand better than the best you've already found. For `count_by_ranks`, if you allocate three bits per rank then overflow into the next rank is impossible since there are only four suits. So e.g. to check for a four of a kind:

```
total_counts = hand_counts + board_counts
possible_fours = total_counts & 0x4924924924
# possible_fours indicates ranks where we have all four cards between hand and board
# We take three cards from board, so rule out ranks where all four are in the board
possible_fours &= ~board_counts
# Similarly, rule out ranks where all four are in hand
possible_fours &= ~hand_counts
# And rule out ranks where three are in hand
possible_fours &= ~((hand_counts << 1) & (hand_counts << 2))
if possible_fours != 0:
  # We have a four-of-a-kind: just need to extract it
```

Comment: `list(h) + list(b)` could be `list(h + b)`

Comment: @AlexHall It actually can't, because `h` and `b` are generators (from `itertools.combinations`). To concatenate two generators you need `itertools.chain`. It's possible that `list(chain(h, b))` might be a little more performant because it creates only one list instead of 3 (but that list is twice the size).

Comment: Thanks, peter. Take a look at the edit on the original post!

Comment: No, h and b are tuples. In fact `h+b` might be good enough on its own without converting to a list.